# How to filter features displayed in WMS layer ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoserver, wms, arcgis-10.4

I've added a WMS layer (from a GeoServer) in ArcMap and trying to apply a filter (~definition Query?) so only features with certain attributes are displayed.

I want to filter on attribute RedlistCategory = CR

Is it possible to do this under layer properties (right click on Map Service in ArcMAP), parameters tab? What should i type in Parameter and Value? Maybe this is not the place to apply filters?

[image]

I've been Reading this but i dont understand what to type in Parameter and Value:
[GeoServer help - WMS vendor parameters](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html)

From the WMS documentation: `&Filter=<Filter><PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>RedlistCategory</PropertyName>
<Literal>CR</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo></Filter>&format=image/tiff`
Is this useful?

[WMS documentation (Swedish)](http://www.slu.se/site/svenska-lifewatch/guider/wfs-och-wms/wms-anrop/)

Comment: I never used ArcGis, but if you can add custom parameters, I'd go for ``CQL_FILTER``, with a value of ``RedlistCategory = "CR"``

Comment: Did you try what @AndreaAime suggested?  If it worked can you write that as an answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From @AndreaAime's comment i added `CQL_FILTER` as Parameter and `RedlistCategory = 'CR'` as value. CR need to be inclosed in ' signs (with " signs i get an error):
[image]

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using?  When I go to the properties for my WMS layer, I do not have a 'Parameters' tab.  I am using ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: @user13706: I Think i was using 10.4. Are you clicking at the right level in the "tree"? In my screenshot i click the "Geoserver Web Map Service" not "All Swedish Occurences"

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I was doing it the way you describe.  I'm upgrading to 10.5 now, and will make sure I have the Interoperability extension installed, so we'll see if that does the trick.

Comment: I believe the issue was that 10.3 did not provide this functionality.  After upgrading to 10.5, and installing the Data Interoperability extension, I have the Parameters tab, like you. I tried disabling the Interoperability extension, and it's still there, so I think it's related to ArcGIS version, not the extension.  Thanks for your quick feedback!