# How can I access custom parameters for WMS layers via ArcObjects, and create a new layer file with the updated parameters?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, arcobjects, wms

I have a set of data in PostGIS related to a large number (7,000) of species, and have a single PostgreSQL view, and corresponding GeoServer layer, that contains data for all species.  Based on input I received for [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243295/how-can-i-serve-data-from-a-single-postgis-view-via-wms-wfs-in-a-way-that-allo/247241#247241), I am using a CQL_FILTER in the custom parameters for an ArcMap layer, to display data for one species at a time, as below:

[image]

This has worked great for me.  Now, I am looking for a way to make it easy for my biologists (who will no doubt make mistakes when editing the CQL_FILTER -- it seems simple, but I could see their eyes glazing over when I tried to explain the process) to see data for a given species.  What I would like to do is to programmatically create one new .lyr file for each species, by editing the CQL_FILTER and saving as a new .lyr file, with an appropriate name for the species, so that biologists can just add the appropriate .lyr file for the species.

I have poked around in the ArcObjects API documentation, but cannot find where these custom parameters are described.  As far as I can tell, they only pertain to web mapping service-type layers.  It seems like these parameters should be accessible via the [WMSMapLayerClass object](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/WMSMapLayerClass_Class/001200000sqs000000/), but I'm not finding any description of it in the documentation.

Comment: If you are using ArcMap 10.5, the API provides [Custom Parameters](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IWMSMapLayer3_CustomParameters.htm)

Comment: That is probably what I was looking for, and couldn't find -- thanks!  I will see if this is what I needed, and post back if so.